# Настройка IDE Rider

Tags: jetbrains, rider

В общем проблема такая , когда писал на Java в Intelij IDEA Удобно было создавать новые объекты , так как было отображено что и где заполняется (Смотреть 1 скриншот ) а в Rider такого нет (2 скрин) , может знает как включить эту штуку ? Заранее спасибо ,надеюсь объяснил доходчиво ! [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Зайдите в настройки IDE:

**Windows**, **Linux**:

> **Settings** | **Editor** | **General** | **Appearance**

**Mac**:

> **Preferences** | **Editor** | **General** | **Appearance**

Затем поставьте галочку **Show parameter name hints**. Нажав на **Configure**, можно провести чуть более подробную настройку.

---

Инструкция выше подходит для большинства IDE от JetBrains, однако Rider данный функционал не поддерживает пока что. Вы можете отследить появление этой фичи, официальный ответ от JetBrains: [ссылка на youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-7971).

Comment: Не сработало !(

Comment: @ДимаКалистратов Очень странно. Что там будет, если нажать **Configure**? Конкретные настройки могут различаться для каждой IDE. Даже для разных языков внутри IDE. То, что я описал, подходит для IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: ВОт скриншот -> http://SSMaker.ru/5fdeb2c2/

Comment: @ДимаКалистратов там сверху выпадающий список у вас, и язык — SQL. Как я понимаю, пишете вы на C#. Выберите в том списке вместо SQL пункт C#, и повторите инструкции, указанные в ответе.

Comment: Там нету C# , есть только TypeScript ,который тож не помогает

Comment: @ДимаКалистратов обновил ответ. Согласно официальному ответу от JetBrains, в вашей IDE данная функция пока ещё не поддерживается.